# Black and white image won't change colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I scanned in an image which into Photoshop. It is black and white written text on a white background.

I am able to select/colour range and grab all of the black elements into a new layer. However I am unable to change the colour of the letters from black to brown.

The image is in RGB (also tried in CMYK) so it's not an issue of greyscale.

I am also able to select a new colour which then appears in my fill, however it does not change the image in any way.

I feel like there will be a simple explanation, but I just can't think what.

I would really REALLY appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: have you selected the layer with the letters? do you know how to use the fill bucket tool? I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this very elementary question is answered fully in the application Help Files.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? I guess you want to put the black text onto another background, so you want all the white to become transparent.

Easiest way in photoshop is to use a layer blend mode.
- make your scanned text into a new layer
- change the layer blend to "Multiply" or "Darken" - you can see which gives best results.

[image]

I edited this after I re-read your post - I see you want to change black text to brown text.
Here's a way:
- Create a new layer, fill it with the shade of brown you want.
- Add the scanned text as a new layer on top of your brown layer
- Change the layer blend mode (of the scanned text) to "Screen"

[image]

Another way without layers is to adjust the brightness/contrast of the scanned text until the background is white and the text is mid-grey. Now you can adjust channels or hue/saturation until you get the text the colour you like:
- go to Brightness/Contrast
- set brightness to maximum
- set contrast to minimum
- go to Hue/Saturation
- set saturation to maximum
- mess with the hue until text colour is desired. turn the saturation down if required.

Cheers
Neil